# linux root unable to create directory

Tags: ubuntu, root

server = Ubuntu 11.04

login as a root, able to create directory, copy file previously few weeks ago, but now try to create directory but failed

```
 mkdir abc

 mkdir: cannot create directory `abc': Read-only file system
```

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Which partition are you trying this on? Is it mounted as read only?

Comment: check if its read only in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your reply. Got the server reboot and solved the problem but how this happen?  root@server:/etc# ls -l /etc/fstab
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 620 2011-05-16 08:24 /etc/fstab  root@server:/etc# cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/xvda1 during installation
/dev/xvda1 /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/xvdb during installation
/dev/xvda2 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: sorry forget to use mini-Markdown formatting.  <br/> im a new here.  <br/> thanks for all the comments.   still unable to make a line-break

Answer (score 1):

Is volume mounted as rw volume? or r only.

mount -oremount,rw /path/to/disk  may work to remount volume as rw but only god can fix it there are other failures.

check status of system message buffer for relevant errors first...

sudo dmesg

Comment: sorry for the late reply. thought using '@TonyStewart' at the previous reply would post to u too. im new here.
Thank for your comment. am able to gain back root's commands after reboot the server but still not sure what caused it.
Thank again ^^

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says: the filesystem is mounted read-only.  Check `dmesg` for any errors, which can cause the filesystem to be automatically switched to read-only mode.

Comment: @TonyStewart sorry for the late reply. i able to gain back root's commands after reboot the server. but still not sure what caused it. ==
Thank psusi and Tony Stewart ^^