# Why do I get permission denied even as root?

Tags: linux, permissions

There is a directory 'dir1' owned by root:root. Stat shows:

```
Access: (0750/drwxr-x---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

and when I log in as root my `id` shows:

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

however when I try to `cd` into that directory I get:

```
-bash: cd: dir1/: Permission denied
```

any ideas why this might be happening and how to remedy it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux root unable to create directory](http://superuser.com/questions/442615/linux-root-unable-to-create-directory)

Comment: What kind of server is this? OpenVZ? Is it hosted somewhere or your own?

Comment: Without knowing which Unix you're running it's impossible to assist.

Comment: I am running RHEL 6.4 and attempting to access a subdirectory of a NFS mount.

Comment: The NFS server may be denying access on the server end for some reason.  Been a while since I've messed with NFS but I think on an NFS server you can deny a host or make permissions map differently.  This would block you even as root locally.  The NFS server itself may also not have permission to write on the remote directory for some reason, i.e. it's read only due to a crash or error.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's SELinux?

Try check with

```
ls -ladZ dir1
```

or try to disable SELinux temporary

```
setenforce 0
# To emable "setenforce 1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the directory in question hosted on NFS?  If so, you might find that root:root is mapped to a safer user (e.g. nobody:guest) on the server.

If you have access to the server, and want remote users to have root privilege, you'll want to add the `no_root_squash` option to the relevant export in `/etc/exports`.  I strongly urge you to read the documentation before doing so.

Answer (score -4):

The directory does not have execute permission, which controls listing its content and entering it. First `chmod +x` and then `cd` into it.

Another possibility could be use of ACL. It can sometimes produce weird errors. Try `cat /etc/fstab | grep acl` and if it is there, try `getfacl dir1`.

Comment: Wrong: the `stat` listing shows that `root` _does_ have execute permission.

Comment: Ah, yes, AFH is correct, I looked badly, sorry.